# I'm writing a self-introduction and need help with some translation

Tags: translation

I need to write a brief self-introduction to find a well-fitting host family for a trip to China, but my language ability is very limited (I'm in my second year of learning Mandarin).

What is a simple way to write "I would like to look around/it would be fun to explore", "I enjoy people watching and am looking forward to learning more about Chinese culture", "I'm shy but I enjoy getting to know people/but I want to make friends", and "I'm half Chinese"?

I tried looking it up first but didn't have much success. It seems like my own (or google translate's) word-for-word English to Chinese translation might be very awkward and there are some words I just haven't learned yet. I would appreciate any other recommendations for writing a self introduction because I know mine is very awkward.

你好！【我姓___，我叫____。】/ 【我姓名_____。】
我十六岁，和我现在在十年级学生。我的家在美国，我是_____高中的学生。现在我的中文不好，但是我要我的中文在进步中。
    我是中美混血。我有妈妈，爸爸，一个姐姐，和一个妹妹。我的家人也有一只狗叫
Sophie。我都非常爱家人。
    我害羞，但是我乐于与不同的人接触，而且我想要交到更多的朋友。我乐于观察人们做事，并且期待学到更多的中国文化。

我的爱好是听音乐，画画，和看书。我很喜欢写故事和诗歌。我成立了我的学校的kpop社团。

Comment: Show us what you have so far on your translations and then we can help.

Comment: I wasn't able to use more eloquent suggestions, because it would be strange to my teacher if she read my introduction and it did not accurately reflect my ability at all. I appreciate all the suggestions very much!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to look around China.
我想到中国四处转转。

It would be fun to explore China.
探索中国肯定会很好玩。

I enjoy people-watching and am looking forward to learning more about Chinese culture.
我乐于观察人们做事，并且期待学到更多的中国文化。

I'm shy but I enjoy getting to know people and I want to make friends.
我害羞，但是我乐于与不同的人接触，而且我想要交到更多的朋友。

I'm half Chinese.
我有一半中国血统。

为什么你的父母不帮你写？他们当中应该有一个人会讲中文吧！

Comment: Thank you! I used the sentences in my summary. My parents can't help me because my mom was born in America and only remembers how to speak a few phrases, or only remembers after I learn how to speak it first.

Answer (score 1):

> *你好！【我姓___，我叫____。】/ 【我姓名_____。】 我十六岁，和我现在在十年级学生。*
>
> **你好！我叫___ 今年十六岁，现在是十年级学生。**

English grammar and Chinese grammar might have difference, but basic writing rules still apply to both. For example, "My name is XX, I am 16 years old, I am a grade ten student" may not be grammatically incorrect, but any decent writer would know to avoid repeating the subject too many times within a series of related sentences and write "My name is XX, I am a 16 years old grade ten student"

"和"(and) in "我现在在十年级学生" is not needed, and this sentence has no verb (I now at ten grade student). The correct structure is " I **am** a ten grade student" (现在**是**十年级学生)

> 我的家在美国，我是_____高中的学生。

Again, you use 我 to start two sentences in a row, but the subject in the first sentence is "我的家" and the subject in the second sentence is "我", therefore not omitting 我 is correct.

If you wrote "我住在美国，(我)是_____高中的学生。" then the subject in the first and second sentence would both be "我". In this case, you should omit the second 我 in the second sentence.

> *现在我的中文不好，但是我要我的中文在进步中。*
>
> **现在我的中文不好，但我会让我的中文进步的。**

我要 sounds like a command, better use 我会让 (I would make)

在进步中 (is improving) is incorrect in this context, you cannot "make your Chinese *is improving*" ; you can only make "your Chinese **to improve**"

Use final particle '的' to indicate the sentence is completed and add tone of 'keenness' in your speech

> *我是中美混血。我有妈妈，爸爸，一个姐姐，和一个妹妹。*
>
> **我是中美混血。我家中有妈妈，爸爸，一个姐姐和一个妹妹。**

"我有妈妈，爸爸" Everyone have father and mother. Your sentence didn't indicate the fact that you are living with them as one family. What you really wanted to say was :"**In my family there's** my father and mother..."

> *我的家人也有一只狗叫 Sophie。我都非常爱家人。*
>
> **我家中还有一只狗叫 Sophie。我非常爱我的家人。**

"我的家人也有一只狗" means "having a dog, same as everyone else"; I think you wanted to say "还" (also) meaning "in addition of all the human family member, we also have a pet dog"

> *我害羞，但是我乐于与不同的人接触，而且我想要交到更多的朋友。*
>
> **我(有点)害羞，但是我(仍然)乐于与不同的人接触，(也)想要交到更多的朋友。**

add "有点" (a little) before "害羞" So that people wouldn't think you are 'too shy'

add "仍然" to indicate despite the fact that you are shy, you **still** are willing to reach out to people.

"(也)想要交到更多的朋友。" is better than "(而且)我想要交到更多的朋友。"

> *我(乐于)观察人们做事，并且期待学到更多的中国文化。*
>
> **我(喜欢)观察人们做事，也很期待学到更多的中国文化。**

You already used 乐于 in the previous sentence, use 喜欢 this time so you wouldn't repeat 乐于 too soon.

Beside, '乐于' could  also mean "willing to" ; while "喜欢" can only mean "like to" . I think it is want you wanted to say.

In this casual format, use "也很" is better, because it is more colloquial than 并且,

> *我的爱好是听音乐，画画，和看书。我很喜欢写故事和诗歌。我成立了我的学校的kpop社团。*
>
> **我的爱好是听音乐，画画，和看书。(也)很喜欢写故事和诗歌。我(还)(创立)了我的学校的kpop社团。**

Comment: I could rewrite your introduction completely and make it sounds like native speaking, but that would not reflect your current ability.

Comment: Thank you for such thorough feedback! I realized that my writing was rather weak (with repeated wording and simple sentences), but I didn't know how to improve it. I'll make the changes now.